# Cannot access map object with []. operator [] is not defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a mobile application using Flutter 1.7.8.

I collected data from the server in a form of a nested json object, e.g.

```dart
class Obj {
  final String obj_to_access;
  const Obj({this.obj_to_access});
  factory Obj.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Obj(
      obj_to_access: json['item']
    );
  }

some_obj = 
{
  "id": some_id,
  "nested_obj": Obj.fromJson(json["obj_to_access"])
}
```

However, I can't seem to access the nested Obj with '[]' and it always give me this error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Obj'. Try defining the operator.

I saw that I should try defining the '[]' but I am not sure how. Please help thanks

Comment: Could you post your JSON String from sever response?

Comment: What do you want the `[]` operator on the `Obj` class to *do*? The `[]` operator is just a normal method with a convenient calling syntax, and `Obj` does not declare any method with that name. My guess is that you want a `toJson` method on your `Obj` objects, because you are storing the `Obj` in a JSON-like map structure, but `Obj` is not itself JSON. Try adding `toJson() => {"item": obj_to_access};` to the `Obj` class and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that you're passing a dynamic value to `Obj.fromJson()` instead of a Map - which it expects. To solve this issue, you can add cast `as <Map<String, dynamic>>` to the value to let the compiler know that it's a Map.